# No syntax highlighting in expanded posts on the review page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, syntax-highlighting

When reviewing posts it can be beneficial to have syntax highlighting but when expanding posts on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) you get no syntax highlighting for code blocks. Is this working as intended or a bug?

Here's an example. The expansion of a post on the review page:

[image: The expansion of a post on the review page]

The *same* post viewed in the question, i.e. the post you get to when you follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045626/fifo-server-program/8046537#8046537) from the review page:

[image: The post viewed in the question]

Note that the latter has got syntax highlighting in the code block.

Comment: This would be especially useful for edits which make use of the  `<!-- language:lang-name -->` language coercion feature.  In the current review mode, you'd see nothing.  In the actual post, though, there would be substantial improvements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty much working as intended, since on the review page, you'd have to implement the "this answer belongs this question, which has these tags, which require this syntax highlighting language" logic to work independently for each post. This is of course possible, but I'm not convinced it's worth the work, since the benefits of this seem pretty small.

Comment: An essential part of the review process is making posts better and one aspect of making a post better is to make them clearer. Code can be unclear and spotting unclear code is made easier by syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also, if the code in a post isn't automatically highlighted, it can be beneficial to see this and add the 'language' comment above the code block