# Add syntax highlighting to expanded posts on the review page

Tags: feature-request, review, syntax-highlighting

It is [intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111386/163868) that there is no syntax highlighting in *expanded* posts on the review page. I disagree with this intention. I think that they should have syntax highlighting. The argument is simple. The review page picks out certain posts that have a higher chance of being of bad quality so that users may review them and act appropriately.

- With syntax highlighting it will be easier to spot posts in which the code formatting needs editing.
- With syntax highlighting it will be easier to spot problems in code that might help in answering the question.

Against this it may be argued that the implementation too much work for too little benefit. I disagree. Many posts need improvement and making it easier to find which to improve is a good thing. An example of this is the two points above. Syntax highlighting might make the difference of whether a problem is spotted or not.

Comment: +1. As you said, it is common for first posts to have no formatting. The current implementation makes no distinction between posts which have no formatting, and those that do.

Comment: To quote a bit more from balpha's answer that you [linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111386/163868): it is *pretty much working as intended, since on the review page, you'd have to implement the "this answer belongs this question, which has these tags, which require this syntax highlighting language" logic to work independently for each post. This is of course possible, but I'm not convinced it's worth the work, since the benefits of this seem pretty small.* So maybe: "It is deemed too much work for too little benefit"?

Comment: @Matt, are you saying that the code formatting is not shown? I thought it was just missing the highlighting, but *is* showing the fixed font formatting?

Comment: @Arjan I think the benefit *is* worth it.

Comment: Very well. It's just that, to me, "intended" makes it feel like it's done on purpose. Like maybe the highlighting was even explicitly *disabled* (rather than simply not implemented). (I'm not native English though.)

Comment: There are also cases where someone used a `<pre>` block instead of a Markdown code block.

Comment: I am in _complete_ agreement with this.